# Toggle active state on different tabs using react inline styles

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from `jQuery` so I'm having issues understanding how to go about this.

I'm writing an application in React and I'm using `inline` styles, i.e. each component have their own styles and they're written in `JS` instead of `CSS`.

Now, I have five tabs and I want to toggle an `.is-active` whenever I click one of them. So on click, I have to remove `.is-active` from the old class, and add it to the clicked class. I'm not sure how to approach this using `inline` styles, because as everything is `inline` there are no actual classes for me to add to my tabs.

Right now, when I render each tab (which I have as a separate component) I also pass in an `isActive` boolean which tells the component to render with or without active classes. Code example of this :

**HTML :**

```
<Tab isActive={true} />
<Tab isActive={false} />
```

**JS :**

```
<div className="tab" style={(this.props.isActive !== true) ? style.tab : {...style.tab, ...style.active}}>
```

But I'm completely lost on how to do this onclick. Do I have to break the inline styling concept to do this, or is there a smart solution? I haven't found anything straightforward online. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [**state**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for this type of implementations.
a brief implementation is like below :

1. suppose you have two Tabs. you should define the state on `constructor` like this :

   ```
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       tabs = [
         { tab1: { active: true } },
         { tab2: { active: false} }
       ]
     }
     this.tabToggle = this.tabToggle.bind(this)
   }
   ```
2. put tab elements into the `render()` :

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         { this.state.tabs.map((tab, index) => 
           <div className={'tab ' + tab.active ? 'active' : ''}>
                onClick={()=>this.tabToggle(index)}>
           </div>
         )}
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```
3. define Toggle function like this :

   ```
   tabToggle(tabIndex) {
     let tabs = this.state.tabs
     tabs[tabIndex] = true
     tabs.map((tab, index) => {
       if (index !== tabIndex) tab.active = false
     })
     this.setState( tabs )
   }
   ```

Some Refrences for parts of Code :

- [**State**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
- [**The Binding**](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/)
- [**Event Handling**](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Amirmohammad has a great answer, but here's a solution that simplifies things and makes your code a bit more DRY:

1. Declare the state with an `activeTab` property (you can even leave out the constructor).

```
state = {
  activeTab: 'tab1',
  tabs: [
    'tab1',
    'tab2',
    'tab3'
  ]
}
```

2. When you render the tab, you can use a ternary operator in className (with a template literal, which I find a bit more readable).

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.tabs.map((tab, index) =>
        <div
          key={`tab-${index}`}
          className={ `tab ${this.state.activeTab === tab ? 'active' : ''}` }
          id={tab}
          onClick={this.handleTabClick}
        >
          {tab}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

3. Finally, we have a handleTabClick function to update the state.

```
handleTabClick = (event) => {
  this.setState({ activeTab: event.target.id });
}
```